# How do I unaccept a hint in Ancestry's online tree system?

Tags: ancestry.com, hints

Some time ago, I confused two people with the same name. I've since split off the extra person and corrected the information for both people, but the "main" person I'm interested in still lists a number of "hints" for the other guy under the "Accepted" tab.

When you ignore a hint, you have the option to "not ignore" it later, but I don't see a corresponding feature for when you accept a hint and want to un-accept it. I've already Googled, and the advice given of removing the sources from the person's Facts and Sources tab doesn't work -- I've already removed all offending source citations.

Comment: Richard, can you clarify, perhaps with an example of the associated data or screenshots you can't get unassociated. I use Ancestry.com for , and I am not clear on what 'exactly' the issue is as a Hint is exactly that and a hint. If you have someone with similar or identical names and close dates it will continue to suggest that hint on both individuals even if you have accepted it on another as it is not that aware.

Comment: I think this is what I call **the uncles & aunts problem**. When I click "Ancestry Member Trees" and then "REVIEW SELECTED TREE HINTS" I am most interested in direct ancestors, so parents are prime. But there's also a fleeting chance to save other children and siblings to my family tree, who are not direct ancestors. That is, great-uncles and great-aunts. After I click "SAVE TO YOUR TREE" I cannot go back and flesh out this extended tree without entering those names individually. I'd prefer to **unaccept** those hints so I could accept a larger portion of them. Is this the same thing?

Answer (score 5):

Removing an accepted hint is a bit more complicated than moving an ignored hint to "not ignore."  Here's what to do:

1. Go to the individual page associated with the person in your family tree to whom the incorrect hint is attached.
2. Click on the "Edit this person" button near the top of the page.
   [image]
3. You'll then be located on the "Edit" page:
   [image]
4. Click on the tab where the incorrect "hint" is likely to be stored: "Relationship Events" for marriage records; "Facts & Events" for census records, burial records, etc.
5. Once you're on the correct page, you'll see a "More Options" button at the far right side of each "fact" or "hint" you've accepted.
   [image]
6. Click on "More Options" and you'll be given the option to "Remove" that "fact" or "hint."
   [image]

Comment: The *information* has already been corrected, and the source citations and links under Facts and Events have already been removed. The problem is the Hints screen -- it still shows all of the "bad" hints as "accepted," even though *nothing* from those sources is cited for this person's facts or relationships anymore.

Answer (score 4):

So you're saying when you click "hints" and then "accepted", the deleted sources still show as accepted?

Personally, I wouldn't have a problem leaving them there. No one else can see them, unless they've been invited to contribute or edit your tree.

To totally fix the problem, you may need to delete the individual and re-enter him. Then you can put the hints in their appropriate accepted/ignored category. But incorrect census records could affect parents/siblings/wife/children. That's a lot of people to delete and re-enter.

Comment: I don't think it's true that nobody else can see them. I think Ancestry uses accepted hints to show you possible tree matches when viewing records.

Comment: I shared a link to this question with Crista Cowan at Ancestry via Twitter.  At 2:52 PM - 24 Feb 2015 Crista tweeted back: "You have to delete the attached record."  I just tested this and determined that @richardtallent is correct. The hint still shows as an Accepted hint, even after the events have been removed, and the source has been deleted from the person's profile.